# Github API, fetch the top most starred public repositories that is written in Python language

Tags: python, pandas, api, github

I am experimenting with Python. What I would like to achieve is using the Github API, I would like to fetch the top 10 most starred public repositories that are written in Python language and are created since last month. Could anyone give me tips on how I could achieve that?

Until now I have managed to achieve the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['repository_ID', 'name', 'URL', 'created_date',  'description', 'number_of_stars'])
results = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars&order=desc').json()

for repo in results['items']:
        d_tmp = {'repository_ID': repo['id'],
                'name': repo['name'],
                'URL': repo['html_url'],
                'created_date': datetime.strptime(repo['created_at'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),


                'number_of_stars': repo['stargazers_count']}
        df = df.append(d_tmp, ignore_index=True)


print d_tmp
```

This gives me the following result for the most viewed sorted by star descending:

```
{'URL': u'https://github.com/faif/python-patterns', 'repository_ID': 4578002, 'number_of_stars': 18103, 'name': u'python-patterns', 'created_date': datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 6, 21, 2, 35)}
```

What I am stuck on is : 
**How to get the same result for last two months and for top 10 repositories?**
 I am thankful for all the valueable information.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Thank you Sean. I will shortly update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `created` parameter of the github api. So to get the python repos since month 9 sorted by stars you can do the following request.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:">2018-09-30"language:python&sort=stars&order=desc
```

Then to get the top 10 repos you can do:

```
top_ten = results['items'][0:10]
```

If you want to restrict the number of items returned on the api call, you can use the `per_page=10` parameter. The query below does the same as above, but returns only 10 results.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:">2018-09-30"language:python&sort=stars&order=desc&per_page=10
```

Good luck on your projects!

Comment: My pleasure! Feel free to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I still have a small question : my results are shown in this format: 'URL': u'https://github.com/santinic/pampy', 'repository_ID': 156706494, 'number_of_stars': 1304, 'name': u'pampy', 'created_date': u'2018-11-08T12:51:17Z' . How would i be able to put a delimeter | after each values instead of ,

Comment: What you are getting is is just the standard way python dictionaries are. If you print you df instead, you will see you get a different formatting.

Comment: Apologize for being stingy haha. What I am expecting is : {'URL': u'https://github.com/santinic/pampy'|'repository_ID': 156706494|'number_of_stars': 1304| 'name': u'pampy'| 'created_date': u'2018-11-08T12:51:17Z'}. Could I change something in my code to get the result :) Thank you so much already and sorry for bothering

Comment: You would have to write a function to transform the dictionary with a string like that. It seems a little weird to put in that format though. I would not advise to do so. If you really want to do it, you can do this: json.dumps(d_temp).replace(',', '|')

Comment: This seems to return different results between runs. I got `donnemartin/system-design-primer, jackfrued/Python-100-Days, nvbn/thefuck` as the top-3 on the first run and `TheAlgorithms/Python, jackfrued/Python-100-Days, huggingface/transformers` on a second run not even an hour later. Also this is a good reminder that the top most starred repos are often not actual libraries.